# «Узнай(,) на что способен твой мозг»

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

Возник вопрос: нужна ли запятая в этой фразе? И почему так, а не иначе?

Answer (score 2):

Нужна. У этих частей разные подлежащее и сказуемое:

- [Ты] узнай,
- мозг способен.

Следовательно, это простые предложения в составе сложносочинённого.

Правила по теме:

- Лопатин: [§ 112 Знаки препинания в сложносочиненном предложении](http://orthographia.ru/punctum_uk.php?rid=351).
- *У Розенталя в [§ 43. Запятая и точка с запятой в бессоюзном сложном предложении](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=148) описано, когда запятую ставить не надо, так что не знаю, как применить это правило к вопросу.*